# Git: get ours/theirs file content during merge

Tags: git

I know I can get the ours/theirs state by invoking

```
git checkout --ours/--theirs -- path/to/my/file.txt
```

but this will overwrite the file in my working tree. How to get the file content of the ours/theirs file state during merge **without overwriting the working tree**?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

[Hidden in the docs :](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge#_how_to_resolve_conflicts)

```
git show :1:file/path   # base
git show :2:file/path   # ours
git show :3:file/path   # theirs
```

---

When a merge conflict is triggered because of a `merge` action, `HEAD` still points to the original commit, and `MERGE_HEAD` to the commit trying to be merged in, so :

```
git show HEAD:file/path        # ours
git show MERGE_HEAD:file/path  # theirs
```

will also work, and perhaps be more explicit to the user.

---

[edit] for completeness: the name of the "theirs" ref changes depending on the action that triggered the conflict:

- `git merge` -> `MERGE_HEAD`
- `git rebase` -> `REBASE_HEAD`
- `git cherry-pick` -> `CHERRY_PICK_HEAD`

Each of these names is simply the name of a file inside the `.git/` directory: if you wonder which one is the correct one just run `ls .git/` (or `ls .git/*_HEAD`) to figure out which variant is present.

---

Another common source of conflicts, as mentioned by @EugenKonkov, is `git stash apply` or `git stash pop`.

There is no extra named ref created in this case, you may still access the `stash` ref though, so `git show stash:file/path` should give your the "theirs" version.

One caveat: if you have run `git stash apply --index` or `git stash pop --index`, conflicts may arise when applying "the index" or "the worktree" -- 2 separate steps.
In that case the correct ref to inspect may be (respectively) `stash^2` or `stash`.

I would say that `git show :3:file/path` is the repeatable, unambiguous way to see "theirs" version in that specific use case.

Comment: Bad design, if it's possible to `git checkout --ours file` it should be possible to do something similar to `git show --ours file`

Comment: Worth knowing that these seem to only work with a relative path in the repo, not with an absolute path.

Comment: `fatal: invalid object name 'MERGE_HEAD'.`

Comment: @EugenKonkov : I updated my answer, does it answer your ( implicit ;) ) question ?

Comment: @LeGEC: No. I tried to do `git stash pop`

Comment: @EugenKonkov: oh right. There is no fancy ref name for that one unfortunately, the most repeatable way will be to access `:3:path` for "theirs". Since the stash is still there, after a plain `git stash pop` you can check `git show stash:path`

Comment: @LeGEC: Thanks for explanations. It would be really better if `git show` will support `--ours` option as was proposed by @Andy

Answer (score 1):

You can use a combination of `git ls-files -u` and `git cat-file blob` to retrieve the different our/their versions.

---

When you have a conflict and run the command `git ls-files -u` it will then give some lines with *file mode value*, *blob id*, *stage value* and *file name*, e.g. something like the following:

```
$ git ls-files -u
100644 ad5e6cfb620eb3086a399bd8dd63f039fa120358 1       .gitignore
100644 73dab4ca75450b2aeb048a5e5632011d95064e58 2       .gitignore
100644 12c32798081dd59a51295275ce1119f5d1662422 3       .gitignore
$
```

The stage values are (details in git-read-tree(1)):

```
0 Normal, no conflict
1 Common ancestor
2 Current branch (version merged on to)
3 The other branch (version merged from)
```

So given the blob id, you can then use `git cat-file blob` to retrieve the corresponding file content, e.g.

```bash
$ git cat-file blob ad5e6cfb620eb3086a399bd8dd63f039fa120358 > .gitignore.common-base
$
```

---

The above is the basis of operation for my script [git-resolve-conflict-using-kdiff3](https://github.com/hlovdal/git-resolve-conflict-using-kdiff3) which does the above automatically and presents you with a choice to launch [KDiff3](https://kdiff3.sourceforge.net/) with all contributing versions for each conflicted file.

Answer (score 0):

when you are invoking:

```
git merge-tool -- file/path
```

git (if configured properly) will launch this tool with all useful file versions: current, theirs, ours, base (file in version of common ancestor of both branches).

There are many tools to help resolve merge conflicts: `kdiff3`, `meld`
My favorite is `beyond compare` (not free - trial has 30 working days for free - if you do not use it it doesn't reduce number of trial days).
It has "three way merge" view, with 4 subviews at top on left is `ours` in middle `base` on right `theirs` at the bottom there is merge result.

Find tool most suitable for you.