# Is it possible to natively get all versions of a file involved in a merge conflict in one line?

Tags: git

https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Advanced-Merging suggests doing the following to get the three files involved in a three-way merge:

```
$ git show :1:hello.rb > hello.common.rb
$ git show :2:hello.rb > hello.ours.rb
$ git show :3:hello.rb > hello.theirs.rb
```

Does Git have anything built-in to do this instead? https://stackoverflow.com/a/44755386/2687324 suggests `git merge-tool` does this for you before launching the tool, so I suspect there should be a way.

Note - it should be possible with aliases:

```
mergefiles = "!f() { git show :1:$1 > $1.common; git show :2:$1 > $2.common; git show :3:$1 > $3.common; }; f"
```

But I don't want to tweak this for edge cases (e.g. if HEAD and MERGE_HEAD added a new file, this fails because the common ancestor doesn't have the file):

```
fatal: Path '<path>' is in the index, but not at stage 1.
Did you mean ':2:<path>'?
```

Comment: How about adding `2>/dev/null` to suppress the error?

Answer (score 0):

`git-mergetool` does a lot, you can [read the source to learn what it does](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/git-mergetool.sh). It's just a shell script and you could potentially reproduce what it does. But it's much easier to take advantage of all that work and write your own mergetool.

[From the git-mergetool docs](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-mergetool)...

> Instead of running one of the known merge tool programs, git mergetool can be customized to run an alternative program by specifying the command line to invoke in a configuration variable mergetool..cmd.
>
> When git mergetool is invoked with this tool (either through the -t or --tool option or the merge.tool configuration variable) the configured command line will be invoked with $BASE set to the name of a temporary file containing the common base for the merge, if available; $LOCAL set to the name of a temporary file containing the contents of the file on the current branch; $REMOTE set to the name of a temporary file containing the contents of the file to be merged, and $MERGED set to the name of the file to which the merge tool should write the result of the merge resolution.

Write a little shell script, put it in your PATH, and make it executable. Be sure to exit with non-zero to indicate the merge "failed".

```
$ cat ~/bin/show-git-mergefiles 
#!/bin/sh

echo Base: $1
echo Local: $2
echo Remote: $3
echo Merged: $4

exit 1
```

Then add it to your `.gitconfig` and pass it the environment variables.

```
[mergetool "show-git-mergefiles"]
        cmd = show-git-mergefiles $BASE $LOCAL $REMOTE $MERGED
        trustExitCode = true
```

And Bob's your parent's brother.

```
$ git mergetool -t show-git-mergefiles
Merging:
file2

Normal merge conflict for 'file2':
  {local}: modified file
  {remote}: modified file
Base: ./file2_BASE_84551
Local: ./file2_LOCAL_84551
Remote: ./file2_REMOTE_84551
Merged: file2
merge of file2 failed
Continue merging other unresolved paths [y/n]?
```

---

Before you that, consider if an existing merge tool does what you want. For example, [vimdiff](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/mergetools/vimdiff).

```
aldsfkalkd           |  aldsfkalkd           |  aldsfkalkd
ldfkjlj              |  ldfkjlj              |  ldfkjlj
another line         |                       |  feature line          
---------------------|  ---------------------|  ----------------------
---------------------|  ---------------------|  ----------------------
---------------------|  ---------------------|  ----------------------
---------------------|  ---------------------|  ----------------------
~                    |  ~                    |  ~                     
~                    |  ~                    |  ~                     
~                    |  ~                    |  ~                     
./file2_LOCAL_82335     ./file2_BASE_82335      ./file2_REMOTE_82335  
aldsfka
ldfk
<<<<<<< HEAD                                                          
another line                                                          
=======                                                               
feature line                                                          
>>>>>>> feature                                                       
~                                                                     
~                                                                     
~                                                                     
~                                                                     
file2
```