# Prevent git pull from modifying file if there is a conflict?

Tags: git, git-pull

When I run `git pull` and there is a conflict, `git` inserts "conflict markers" into my file and set the file state to some sort of pending-merge or some sutch. Personally I find this **really** annoying as I have access to *much* better ways to resolve conflicts than trying to decode what it thought the merge was from a flat text file.

Is there any way to prevent git from ever generating those markers? Specifically I want for all commands, including a bare `git pull`, to do nothing if there would be a conflict, no matter what state things start in.

By implication what I'm looking for is a change to the git configuration. A change to my workflow (e.g. "always commit before pull") is not what I'm looking for.

Ideally, I'd like it to do absolutely nothing to my local files if it can't do a perfectly clean merge but instead just print an error and tell me to fix it on my own.

Comment: You just need to take the habit of `git commit`-ing before any `git pull` (so do only `git pull` on tree without modifications reported by `git status`)

Comment: What are those "much better ways"? Git supports various merge tools.

Comment: @Basile Starynkevitch That might be useful for some cases, but lets assume that I'm dealing with a case where it's not, because I am. (E.g. I have some edits made but it's in state that is valid enough to commit, even locally.)

Comment: `git fetch origin foo && git merge-tree $(git merge-base HEAD FETCH_HEAD) HEAD FETCH_HEAD`. It works in most cases.

Comment: @Schwern, Somewhat beside the point, but "using the editor that I already have open in another window"

Comment: @ElpieKay I'm not looking for something to replace `git pull` with, but rather a way to make running `git pull` fail differently. I've update the question to avoid that ambiguity.

Comment: You need to use `git` more efficiently. You could make local branches

Comment: @BCS Turns out Git can use your editor for merging. You have an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). And yes, a change to your workflow will help. Don't fight the tool.

Comment: @Schwern It can? How? I have good reason the believe that my already running editor process can't be manipulated by other processes in the way that would be needed. If Git can't manipulate it, it can't use it.

Comment: @BCS Read the answers, you can set up a merge tool to open the conflict files in an existing editor. But really a good editor should see that the file has changed and show you the conflicted version automatically. See my answer for an example.

Comment: @BCS If you don't want those markers, after `git pull`, you could simply run `git checkout --ours .` so that the conflict files still hold the previous content and `git status` tells which files need manual resolving.

Comment: Did you rule out simply doing 'git merge --abort' (when needed) for a reason ?

Comment: @RomainVALERI what I'd like is to have the same effect as what `git config --global merge.tool 'git merge --abort'` would do, assuming it would work at all. Or even better, instruct it to just totally fail if a merge would be needed.

Answer (score 2):

There's a few ways to deal with this.

First is to get used to it. Those are standard conflict markers used by most merge tools. You'll be seeing them a lot.

> *[I want to resolve the conflict] using the editor that I already have open in another window*

A good editor will see when the file has changed on disk and show you the conflicted version. If your editor doesn't do that, might be a configuration option, or it might be time for a new editor that has better filesystem awareness. Many editors understand these markers and will provide syntax coloring and other assistance. [Atom](https://atom.io/), for example, does all this out of the box.

[image]

If there's a merge tool you prefer, you can use that by configuring and then running `git mergetool` when there's a conflict. Git will start your configured merge tool and you can use it to resolve the conflict. This includes opening the files in your editor.

If there's not an existing mergetool adapter that does what you want, you can write one. Have a look at [`vimdiff`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/mergetools/vimdiff) for an example, and also [this answer demonstrating writing your own merge tool](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50547512/14660).

---

Then there's various ways to avoid conflicts on `git pull` in the first place.

One is to not make any commits to `master`. Instead do all your work in feature branches. These are branches you make to work on a single feature or bug. Even the simple ones. They isolate your work from everybody else's until you're done. Work in the branch until the feature is complete.

```
# After `git checkout -b feature` and some commits.
          [origin/master]
A - B - C [master]
         \
          D - E - F [feature]
```

Meanwhile, you can `git pull` on `master` to update as often as you like. With no local changes there will be no conflicts.

```
# After `git pull` on `master` to get other's work.
                  [origin/master]
A - B - C - G - H [master]
         \
          D - E - F [feature]
```

You can keep your feature branch updated with the latest work from other people with `git rebase master` to replay your work on top of `master`. Using `rebase` instead of `merge` avoids unnecessary merges that are just bookkeeping and simplifies the history.

```
# After `git rebase master`
                  [origin/master]
A - B - C - G - H [master]
                 \
                  D1 - E1 - F1 [feature]
```

When you're done with your work in `feature`, update `master` one last time, merge in your feature branch, and push `master`. Use `git merge --no-ff feature` to retain the existence of the feature branch for future archeology.

```
# After `git merge --no-ff feature`
                 [origin/master]
A - B - C - G - H ------------- I [master]
                 \            /
                  D1 - E1 - F1 [feature]

# After `git push`
                                  [origin/master]
A - B - C - G - H ------------- I [master]
                 \            /
                  D1 - E1 - F1 [feature]
```

Then delete the branch. The topography of the history will retain its existence. This helps future code archeologists to understand your code by showing what commits were grouped together as a single feature.

```
                                  [origin/master]
A - B - C - G - H ------------- I [master]
                 \            /
                  D1 - E1 - F1
```

---

Finally, if you *really* want to do it your way, you can use `git checkout --ours` to checkout your clean version. It's "ours" because when you `git pull` you're really doing `git fetch` + `git merge origin/master`. `master` is "ours" and `origin/master` is "theirs".

I do not recommend this as you now have to manually perform the merge yourself defeating the point of using a merge tool. You're very likely to make a mistake causing more conflicts.

Comment: Your mention of `git mergetool` solve it: All I needed to do was run `git config --global merge.tool /bin/false`

Comment: @BCS \*headdesk\*

Comment: FWIW, the rest of you answer is rather useful. *However* what you are spending time trying to explain strongly indicates that you are trying to solve a different problem than I'm trying to solve. You are pointing out the correct way to do things. What I'm looking for is a way to make stuff fail faster when, by error or otherwise, I attempt to do the wrong thing. If I `pull` the wrong branch, or `merge` when I intended to `rebase` I want it to fail without modifying the files. I want it to do nothing.

Comment: @BCS There's likely better ways to deal with those problems as well. Perhaps you should [ask about the problem you're trying to solve with this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), you'll probably get better solutions.

Comment: The problem I'm trying to solve is "If I mismanaged a branch by mistake, it adds a bunch of garbage conflict markers and modified the git state of the files". What I want is for it to just refuse to do anything when I make that sort of mistake. ("Hay you dope! You did something wrong! No soup for you!") --- BTW, even setting `merge.tool` isn't quite strong as I'd like because it still results in the file being in a pending merge state.

Comment: @BCS You should ask that as a proper question with more detail. There are far better ways to deal with it, and probably ways to improve your workflow to avoid it in the first place.

Comment: @BCS If you just want to stop a mistaken merge that resulted in conflicts, `git merge --abort`.

Answer (score 1):

Usual workflow in git is to call `git mergtool` after merge failure. Mergetool can be called with any program you like: `kdiff3`, `bcompare`, `p4merge` by command:

```
git mergetool [--tool=<tool>].
```

You even can use some custom tool. To set default mergetool

```
 git config --global merge.tool [tool]
```

Read [there](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Configuration) about configuting.